# What are the yaml files in config/project? Should I commit them?

Tags: craft3, config

See the title. I'm currently committing the YAML files to our git repo so they deploy to our production server. Is that appropriate? Should I ignore the config/project folder?

Answer (score 1):

Those are your [Project Config](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/project-config.html) files.

You'll definitely want to 1) read up on it so you're using it properly and 2) commit those files to your repo. :)